# How to handle database transactions in Generic Repository?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-3.0

I'm working on `ASP.NET Core WebAPI` with `EFCore 3`.
How can I handle transactions in Generic Repository approach? I'm aware of Repository patterns pros and cons, as well as its generic repository approach, but something that confuses me is how to handle transactions while using them??

Below is `BaseRepository` I use. I have a problem implementing transaction like this:

1. Add `Employee`
2. Get created `EmployeeId`
3. Add `Employee`'s address with just created `EmployeeId`

The problem I have is that I **must** call `SaveChanges` to get autogenerated Employee's Id, to be able to insert Employee's address. `SaveChanges` commits the transaction (created by EF Core).
How can I do this in transaction, while using `BaseRepository`? Should I expose `BeginTransaction` and `Commit` methods in BaseRepository, so that `Service` class can create the transaction and close it?

```
    public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> 
        where TEntity : class, IEntity
    {
        private readonly DemoDb_context _context;

        public BaseRepository(DemoDb_context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<TEntity> GetById(int id)
        {
            return await _context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
        }

        public async Task<List<TEntity>> GetAll()
        {
            return await _context.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<TEntity> Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return entity;
        }

        public async Task<TEntity> Delete(int id)
        {
            var entity = await _context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
            if (entity == null)
            {
                return entity;
            }

            _context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return entity;
        }

        public async Task<TEntity> Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return entity;
        }
    }
```

This is my service class, where I think, I should add transaction:

```
public class EmployeeService
{
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;
    private readonly IAddressRepository _addressRepository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public EmployeeService(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository, IAddressRepository addressRepository, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
        _addressRepository = addressRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<EmployeeDto> Add(EmployeeDto employeeDto)
    {
        // TODO: Start transaction here ???

        var employee = _mapper.Map<Employee>(employeeDto);
        var addedEmployee = await _employeeRepository.Add(employee);

        var employeeAddress = Generate_Employee_Address_Entity_With_EmployeeId(addedEmployee); 
        var addedAddress = await _addressRepository.Add(employeeAddress);

        var output = Generate_Employee_Dto(addedEmployee, addedAddress); 

        // TODO: Commit transaction here ???

        return outputs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages of entity framework is that you can avoid using transactions in base case scenarios like the one you showed us. I would suggest the following:

1. In BaseRepository remove the SaveChangesAsync from Add, Update and Delete methods and expose a method called SaveDbChangesAsync().

   ```
     public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> 
           where TEntity : class, IEntity
       {
           private readonly DemoDb_context _context;

           public BaseRepository(DemoDb_context context)
           {
               _context = context;
           }

           public async Task<TEntity> GetById(int id)
           {
               return await _context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
           }

           public async Task<List<TEntity>> GetAll()
           {
               return await _context.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();
           }

           public async Task<TEntity> Add(TEntity entity)
           {
               _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
               return entity;
           }

           public async Task<TEntity> Delete(int id)
           {
               var entity = await _context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
               if (entity == null)
               {
                   return entity;
               }

               _context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);    
               return entity;
           }

           public async Task<TEntity> Update(TEntity entity)
           {
               _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
               return entity;
           }

           public async Task SaveDbChangesAsync()
           {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
           }
       }
   ```

In this way you do not store changes to the database but changes are only tracked in memory in the context.

2. When you are done with all your logic you can call the SaveDbChangesAsync() method from your service class (in general the class that is using the repository) and persist the change.

   ```
   public class EmployeeService
   {
       private readonly IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;
       private readonly IAddressRepository _addressRepository;
       private readonly IMapper _mapper;

       public EmployeeService(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository, IAddressRepository addressRepository, IMapper mapper)
       {
           _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
           _addressRepository = addressRepository;
           _mapper = mapper;
       }

       public async Task<EmployeeDto> Add(EmployeeDto employeeDto)
       {
           // TODO: Start transaction here ???

           var employee = _mapper.Map<Employee>(employeeDto);
           var addedEmployee = await _employeeRepository.Add(employee);

           var employeeAddress = Generate_Employee_Address_Entity_With_EmployeeId(addedEmployee); 
           var addedAddress = await _addressRepository.Add(employeeAddress);

           var output = Generate_Employee_Dto(addedEmployee, addedAddress); 


           //// Here instead of commit transaction, we save changes to
           //// the database. If anything goes wrong changes will be discarded 
           //// anyways when you context gets out of scope;
           await SaveDbChangesAsync();

           return outputs;
       }
   ```

Benefits:

1. Avoid to use a performance heavy operation like Transactions
2. You use EF in the right way

However if you insist using transactions you can do the following:

```
using (EntitiesContext context = new EntitiesContext())  
{  
    using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())  
    {  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Correct me, if I'm wrong, but I think that `Add` method (in repository) will NOT return `Id` of the new Employee. Therefore how can you insert Address to the database, if you don't have Employee's Id? The whole point of my question is: I must use `SaveChanges` to be able to get auto-generated Id, which will be used in Address table.

Comment: Ok now I get what you want to do. You have two options: 1) You wrap your whole functionality into a transaction as showed at the answer. 2) You can use the SQL concept of sequence that you can create the primary key but it will not be an auto increment any more.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15